# Migrate a table from MS Access to SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

How to migrate a table from MS Access to SQL Server 2012?

Suppose I am inserting data in MS Access, how will it get upgraded in SQL Server 2012 without dropping or recreating a table?

Comment: Use Sql Server Data import Export Wizard.

Answer (score 1):

From MS Access:

Select **'Database Tools'** from the Ribbon, inside there's the **'SQL Server'** option (also called *Upsize Wizard*). Once in the wizard you can choose between creating a new table on the SQL Server database of your choice or using an existent table (if you choose to use an existent table you are to make sure the field types on your Access database match the ones on your SQL Server one).

In the next steps you must select your SQL Server instance and also which fields you want to upsize along with indexes, table relationships, etc.

> Suppose I am inserting data in MS Access, how will it get upgraded in
>   SQL Server 2012 without dropping or recreating a table

I'm not very clear on what you mean here, if what you mean is to have an Access frontend where you collect data and you want it to 'send' this data also to an SQL Server database (which sounds very eclectic, btw) you can use VBA for that.

Heres a discussion on the matter that would do just that: [VBA to Append Access data to SQL Server Table](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=274295)

If this is not the case then you'll need to update your question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Like @AA.SC suggested you can use the "SQL Server Import and Export Wizard" and use the Access Database as a data source:

[image]

But if you need to keep the tables in access and just need to have a copy of the data in SQL Server you can create a SSIS job to import it and create a copy of the table.

Hard to say more without more information about your issue.